# sum multiple list elements at the same time(python)

Tags: python, list, sum

How can I sum multiple list elements at the same time?
For example, something like this in Python:

Our lists (input):

```
[3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Output:

```
[4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Note: we don't know how many list will be given to us.

Comment: Zip the lists together and sum them: `[sum(t) for t in zip(lstA, lstB)]`.

Comment: _we don't know how many list will be given to us_ How are you getting these lists?

Comment: it is a function that gives us a tuple of lists , i solved my problem with your great solution in this way :[sum(t) for t in zip(*lists)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job

```py
l1 = [3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
l2 = [1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

l3 = [sum(t) for t in zip(l1, l2)]
    
print(l3)
```

Comment: What if the user is provided a varying number of lists?

Comment: your right forgot about that il update my code!

Comment: `[sum(t) for t in zip(*lists)]` where `lists` contains any number of lists.

Answer (score 1):

As we don't know how many lists there will be, and I assume their lengths could be different, using the `zip_longest` function from `itertools` is the perfect tool:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
    
l1 = [3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
l2 = [1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
l3 = [1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, -1]
l4 = [-105]

lists = [l1,l2,l3,l4]

summed = list(map(sum,zip_longest(*lists,fillvalue=0)))
print(summed)
```

Output:

```
[-100, 5, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily and efficiently using pandas.

```
lists = [[3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=lists)
out = df.sum().tolist()
```

print(out):

```
[4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

It should work with any number of lists.

Comment: I really like `pandas`, but in this case the simplest answer is `out = [sum(t) for t in zip(*lists)]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I didn't time it, but pandas operations are vectorized and should be faster.

Comment: I timed it.  I made sure the pandas import was outside of the timing. The `pandas` solution on your example data was ~450 times slower. Possibly, a larger dataset may have evened the score. One thing to note is that creating the `DataFrame` involves iteration over Python lists so that's something you pay for with both solutions.  I tried moving `DataFrame` creation to setup and making the lists 1000x larger and the non-pandas solution was still ~10 times faster.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I agree the setup needs time. But timing is sometimes tricky.

Answer (score 0):

If you have varying number of list as input , you can try the below.,

note : input the numbers in list as comma-seperated values

---

**Console**

1,2,3

2,3,1

[3, 5, 4]

---

```
import pandas as pd

ls = []
while True:
    inp = input()
    if inp == "":
        break
    ls.append(list(map(int,inp.split(","))))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ls)
out = df.astype(int).sum().tolist()
print(out)
```